# why is calcite using SEARCH operator in the plan when I issue BETWEEN operator in the query

Tags: apache-calcite

I am issuing a query like: "select col1 a, col2 b from tableA where a between 100 and 101" to my calcite based jdbc driver.

The calcite query plan uses a SEARCH operator for the between filter. However I see calcite has a BETWEEN operator in org.apache.calcite.sql.fun.

Any ideas? Its using also SEARCH when I use IN in my sql. I am ok with that. But why SEARCH for BETWEEN.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly where this happens will depend on how you are using Calcite. Since you haven't provided any code, this is not possible to say. However, this happens as part of Calcite's simplification of row expressions in `RexSimplify`. You can find more information on [the associated JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-4173) where implementation of the `SEARCH` operator was proposed.